# Sum function doesn't give sufficient decimal places with divide function

Tags: sql

I have the following sql query that I am running:

```
select sum(cast(mkt_value as decimal(20,7)))/1204438043.37 from table1
```

and I get the following result which is correct but I need at least 10 decimal places not 6:

0.009347

If I run the following query:

```
select sum(mkt_value) from table1
```

I get 11258490.2400.

If I divide 11258490.24 by 1204438043.37 in excel I get 0.009347504674 which is the answer I'm looking for.

Please help me correct my SQL!!

Comment: your table mkt_value column data type and size ?

Answer (score 4):

Your cast is breaking this. It doesn't have enough space to give you more than six decimal places. What you're saying is literally "give me the result of this division with at most six decimal places", and then you're suprised the result only has six decimal places :)

The solution is either to omit the cast (if the data type is `money`, it's fine) or increase the `scale` of the `decimal`, eg. `decimal(20, 11)`. The second parameter of the `decimal` type says the maximal amount of decimal places (-1) in the number. Also, consider only casting the result of the sum instead of all the items.

Note that most operations in MS SQL return a value of the same data type. So:

```
select 3 / 4; -- Returns 0
select cast(1000 as smallint) * cast(1000 as smallint); 
-- Error - 1 000 000 is too big for smallint
```

The same thing happens in your `sum` and also in the division that happens right after it :)

Comment: I can't omit the CAST as the result gives 0.009347. data type of mkt_val is decimal(18,4).

Comment: @Andrew Don't omit it then, increase the limit - eg. `decimal(30, 11)` (ideally, cast the result of the `sum` to this, and omit the cast inside the `sum`). `decimal(20, 7)` simply isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply casting after calculating final value

```
select CAST (sum(mkt_value)/1204438043.37 as decimal(15,10)) from table1.
```

This means result would be having maximum 15 digits and mandatory 10 decimal places.

Comment: Unfortunately that just gives 0.0093470000 not the 0.009347504674 or alike.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following query,Since your final decimal places are getting truncated.Hence a cast would be required to your final result set.

```
select 
cast(cast (sum(mkt_value) as decimal(20,7))/cast (1204438043.37 as decimal(20,7)) as decimal(20,12)) from table1
```

Thank you..Let me know if this works